# How to Windows Mobile 6.5+Fusion Launcher connect to 802.1x Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi, windows-mobile

How to Windows Mobile 6.5+Fusion Launcher connect to 802.1x Wi-Fi ?

I try to add SSID to connect Wi-Fi with WPA2 Enterprise+PEAP+MSCHAP V2+AES but cannot connect to 802.1x Wi-Fi.